# Electron APP - Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: selenium-webdriver, electron, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-java

We are using an application with node 18.18.2, electron browser version 28.1.4 and chrome 120.0.6099.216

[image]

Trying to launch the app using selenium as coded below.

```
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> cloudOptions;
opt.setPlatformName("Windows 10");
opt.setBrowserVersion("120");
logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
opt.setProxy(startProxyServer());
opt.setCapability("goog:loggingPrefs", logPrefs);
opt.setBinary(new File(Constants.APPPATH));
cloudOptions = new HashMap<>();
opt.setCapability("cloud:options", cloudOptions);
//WebDriverManager.chromedriver().driverVersion("112.0.5615.28").clearDriverCache().setup();
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().driverVersion("120.0.6099.109").clearDriverCache().setup();
System.out.println("Before Driver creation:");

webDriver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
```

Getting error:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
> At webDriver = new ChromeDriver(opt);

Please suggest possible fix/solutions for this issue?

Assuming it is a driver compatibility issue we tried with multiple chromedrivers `120.0.6099.28`, `120.0.6099.56`, `120.0.6099.62`, `120.0.6099.71` and `120.0.6099.109` for chrome version `120.0.6099.216`. using below code still we are getting the same error.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Path\\chromedriver-win64 (1)\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
```